# javascript - don't add class for specific css class

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm working with a template in Wordpress that someone else set up and I need to fix something.

There is a javascript function that adds a class to every css class that's called `object-fit` - the added class is called `bg--image`. This was to fix an error showing up in IE11 , where all the images where messed up.

The problem now is that there's a page where this function shouldn't apply even though the css class is also called `object-fit`.

I'm a little confused on how to work here. As I don't want to mess up the whole theme and my coding options are quite limited, it just makes a knot in my brain.

Is there any possibility I can add a javascript function to not apply the IE 11 function on this one specific class? the difference is that the one img where it shouldn't apply is a `span`, the other one is not.

Any ideas?

```js
try {
  if (ie_ver() == 11) {
    var $img = $('.banner--small').find('img');
    $('.banner--small').attr('style', 'background-image:url(' + $img.attr('src') + ')');
    $('.banner--small').addClass('bg--image');
    $img.addClass('hidden');

    var $img2 = $('.object-fit').find('img');
    $('.object-fit').attr('style', 'background-image:url(' + $img2.attr('src') + ')');
    $('.object-fit').addClass('bg--image');
    $img2.addClass('hidden');

    $('.slick__inner').each(function() {
      var $img3 = $(this).find('img');
      $(this).attr('style', 'background-image:url(' + $img3.attr('src') + ')');
      $(this).addClass('bg--image');
      $img3.attr('style', 'display:none');
    });
```

```html
<div class="article--text">
  <div class="container container--tiny spacing--huge">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="container margin-bottom--huge">
    <?php if (get_field('direktionen')) { ?>
    <div class="flex flex--wrap flexgrid--gutter flexgrid--normal">
      <?php foreach (get_field('direktionen') as $key => $child) { ?>
      <div class="flex__item one-third lg-one-half xs-one-whole">
        <a href="<?php echo $child['link']; ?>" class="link--direction text--center margin-bottom--medium" target="_blank">
          <span class="object-fit"><img src="<?php echo $child['photo']['sizes']['medium']; ?>" 
          srcset="<?php echo $child['photo']['sizes']['mobile']; ?> 2x,<?php echo $child['photo']['sizes']['medium']; ?> 1x" 
          alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" /></span>
          <h3>
            <?php echo $child['name']; ?>
          </h3>
          <p>
            <?php echo $child['adresse']; ?>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } else if ($children) { ?>
    <div class="flex flex--wrap flexgrid--gutter flexgrid--normal">
      <?php foreach ($children as $key => $child) { ?>
      <div class="flex__item one-third lg-one-half xs-one-whole">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($child->ID); ?>" class="link--direction text--center margin-bottom--medium">
          <span class="object-fit"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($child->ID, 'medium'); ?>" 
          srcset="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($child->ID, 'mobile'); ?> 2x,<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($child->ID, 'medium'); ?> 1x"
          alt="<?php echo $child->post_title; ?>" /></span>
          <h3>
            <?php echo $child->post_title; ?>
          </h3>
          <p>
            <?php echo get_field('adresse', $child->ID); ?>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to add another class to the elements to which the activity should not apply. A given selector string always means the same thing, but with another class to flag the special elements you could add a `:not()` clause to the selector.

Comment: Also DRY - don't repeat yourself. The PHP IF with identical html should be html with a test for direktionen where needed

Comment: _“the difference is that the one img where it shouldn't apply is a span, the other one is not”_ - so `.object-fit:not(span)` then …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a WordPress template, you have a couple of solutions.

**Solution 1 - HTML & jQuery modification**

If you can add an additional class to only this page's HTML, then applying the following updates to this page template should allow you to avoid having the .bg--image class added to just this page:

HTML

```
 <span class="object-fit avoid-change">
```

jQuery

```
$('.object-fit').not( '.avoid-change' ).addClass('bg--image');
```

More info on jQuery's .not() method:
https://api.jquery.com/not/

---

**Solution 2 - WordPress Conditional**

Another option is to use a WordPress conditional to avoid running the entire script on this page.

You could use the following to prevent the script from loading in this template:

```
<?php if(! is_page_template( 'your-template-name.php' )){  ?>
   // place your script or wp_enqueue_script() code here
<?php } ?>
```

You could also target an exact page by its page ID. In this example, your page ID would be 7.

```
<?php if(! is_page( '7' )){  ?>
   // place your script or wp_enqueue_script() code here
<?php } ?>
```

More info on WordPress conditionals:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags